¿Por qué las notificaciones push de firebase sólo funcionan el primer día en mi app flutter? a pesar de estar configuradas como diarias
Como menciono en el título, tengo una aplicación hecha en flutter, en la cual implementé notificaciones push a través de firebase; el problema es que las notificaciones llegan solamente el primer día y otras veces el primer y segundo día, pero luego dejan de llegar.
Les agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme!
Esta es mi función principal:
/// HE PROBADO CON ESTE CÓDIGO Y SIN ÉL, PERO PASA LO MISMO.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await requestNotificationPermissions();
  await initNotifications(); 
  await _initGoogleMobileAds(); 
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized(); 
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); 
  runApp(
    Phoenix (
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UiProvider()), 
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => MyState()), 
        ],
        child:
        EasyLocalization(
            path: 'assets/lang',
            supportedLocales: const [
              Locale('en'),
              Locale('es'),
            ],
            fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
            //startLocale: Locale('es'),
            child: MyApp()),
      ),
    ),
  );
}


Este es mi archivo android manifest, he probado añadiendo permisos y diferentes códigos que supuestamente ayudarían a recibir las notificaciones, pero no hay caso, las notificaciones llegan a la hora deseada el primer día y luego dejan de llegar.
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
        android:label="Mi Verso Diario Lite"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <!--:::::::::::::::: PARA RECIBIR NOTIFICACIONES PROGRAMADAS ::::::::::::::::::::::-->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass,WrongManifestParent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass,WrongManifestParent" />
    <!--This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java: -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
    </application>
     <!-- This queries is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin.-->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>



